# Debug OpenJDK14 using CLion: failed to load the CMake project

Tags: java, c++, cmake

I download the source code of OpenJDK14 and put them in `\home\yuanfang\jdk14` and after running `bash configure --disable-warnings-as-errors` and `make images`, I build OpenJDK14 successfully, The newly built JDK is in `home\yuanfang\jdk14\build\linux-x86_64-server-release\jdk`. By the way, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Then I want to debug OpenJDK14 using CLion IDE. I was using CLion 2020.2 and I take the following steps:

1. After open CLion I choose **Create New CMake Project from Sources** and choose the directory of `\home\yuanfang\jdk14`, which is the root directory of the jdk project.
2. I alter the **Run/Debug Configurations** to make it look like this:
   [image: Run/Debug configurations]
3. CLion create a `CMakeLists.txt` automatically but the file doesn't work, so after googling I find find the correct `CMakeLists.txt` here at https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/blob/master/src/java-14-openjdk/CMakeLists.txt. I then rewrite the old `CMakeLists.txt` using the correct one.
4. I download the whole repository(that is, [github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild)), unzip it and put it into `\home\yuanfang\jdk14`.
   It looks like as follow, the `ojdkbuild-master` is the newly added folder.
   [image]
5. I reload the CMake project, but some CMake error occurs(as follow), why can't CLion find those files? javaI googled but can't find any effective solution. Is there anything I can do or refer to? Thanks in advance.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/yuanfang/jdk14/../../resources/cmake/ojdkbuild_common.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/yuanfang/jdk14/../../resources/cmake/version.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:93 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source
  "/home/yuanfang/jdk14/../../deps/rhino/scripting_tasks" which is not an
  existing directory.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:98 (ojdkbuild_add_subdirectory):
  Unknown CMake command "ojdkbuild_add_subdirectory".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yuanfang/jdk14/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Cannot get compiler information:
    Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/bin/cc -xobjective-c -I/home/yuanfang/jdk14/build/linux-x86_64-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/gensrc/adfiles......./loading/LibraryLoader/jar_src -g -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/home/yuanfang/jdk14/build/linux-x86_64-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/gensrc/adfiles' '-I' '......'-g' '-fpch-preprocess' '-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     cc1obj -E -quiet -v @/tmp/cci3XM6r -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END /tmp/compiler-file5929385022787926768 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fpch-preprocess -g -fworking-directory -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -dD
    cc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    
    

[Failed to reload]
```

Comment: I do find `ojkbuild_common.cmake` in `\home\yuanfang\jdk14\ojkbuild-master\resources\cmake\ojkbuild_commin.cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

1. step: check out this projecdt :https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild.git
2. step: put the source code of OpenJDK14 in ojdkbuild/src/
3. step: copy reousrces directory and CMakelists.txt to OpenJDK14
4. step： recomile openjdk and import project to CLin